# How can I create a Web Api 2 Route when I have a folder of the same name?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In an empty Web Api 2 project, I have removed the Controllers folder generated by the project template, and started using feature folders (as opposed to types folders).

I have an Organizations controller in an organizations folder, i.e.

```
/organizations
----OrganizationsController.cs
```

The OrganizationsController is simple:

```
[RoutePrefix("organizations")]
public class OrganizationsController : ApiController
{
    public const string GetAllOrganizationsRouteName = "GetAllOrganizations";
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Name = GetAllOrganizationsRouteName)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllOrganizations()
    {
        return Ok(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

This results in a 403 when requesting {base}/organizations. IIS believes I'm trying to browse the organizations directory, which is disabled by IIS. How can I tell IIS and/or Asp.Net to stop trying to follow the physical structure and only respect the Route attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working around the issue by introducing a /web folder to the project root. OrganizationsController is now located at /web/organizations/OrganizationsController. This works fine because the /organizations route no longer matches a physical directory. If there is a way to turn this off with config please post another answer.